# Reusing Bitmap to Decode JPEG Data

Tags: .net

This part of my application displays a real-time image stream from an IP camera in a picture box. The stream is a typical motion JPEG formatted as a multi-part HTTP response.

All the code is written, my app works fine with very low CPU usage (1-2%) and a see-saw memory footprint (gradually increases until a GC is triggered then it's all recycled back down to normal). So this is more of an optimization question, best of practice etc, it's not required.

With that out of the way, right now I'm doing this in the normal `Bitmap.FromStream()` fashion, which generates a whole new bitmap for every frame, at 60Hz. Even if it's fine from a run-time perspective, that's jarring for me as a programmer.

If I were to use a more hands on approach, I'd preallocate the bitmap with known size (320x240 or 640x480, depending on options) and just decode the stream into my bitmap, but I don't see a .NET function that does this. I'd have to use my own JPEG decoder, which is both too much work, and more binary size (this thing is already 55mb of compiled code).

So my question is, am I missing something here? Is there a best way to do something like this? The function I mentioned would be perfect, but if not available, how else would I improve this?

Comment: Are you invoking dispose() on each bitmap object? It will help with memory management, as Bitmap uses both managed an unmanaged memory.

Comment: Irrelevant to my question, but no. Disposing it myself would bring it on my UI thread, instead of letting the GC do it on its own finalizer thread. There's no real gains to it, the GC disposes bitmaps 30-40mb in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that getting 2% cpu load from 60 fps jpegs is a *very* good result.  Very little you can do to make that substantially better.  Do make sure your benchmark is realistic, you cannot be doing much with the bitmap data when it gets this low.  A potential trap is that the codec converts the compressed pixel data lazily.  If you never actually, say, call Graphics.DrawImage() or Bitmap.LockBits() then the codec doesn't do anything more but parse the header.  The .NET object you get is also *very* modest, just 20 bytes of GC heap is required.

There is fairly little reason to fear the underlying memory management.  It is extremely opaque in GDI+, it completely takes care of it by itself without exposing anything more than a pointer.  Image.FromFile() is by far superior, GDI+ uses a memory-mapped file to access the raw pixel data.  No use for that in a camera app of course, Image.FromStream() is more involved due to the impedance mismatch between GC and native memory, there's a Marshal.Copy() under the hood to shovel bytes.  The codec is likely to allocate itself to buffer/cache decoded pixels, you have no control over this whatsoever.  No reason to fear this since you repeatedly use the exact same allocation, the Windows memory manager likes that a lot.

What you are asking for *is* possible.  Two basic ways to do it.  First one is the [Bitmap constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/zy1a2d14%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an IntPtr, it needs to point to decoded pixel data.  Which lets you re-use the raw pixel buffer.  Second way is [Bitmap.LockBits()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can directly scribble into the pixel buffer that GDI+ allocated.  There is no fundamental difference between the two.

You do need to bring your own JPEG decoder when you do this of course.  The [libjpeg library](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) is the most commonly used one.  Written in C, best way to incorporate it is with a C++/CLI wrapper.  The libjpeg-turbo library is notable, promising 2-4x faster decodes.  No real idea how these libraries compare to Microsoft's codec.  Pay attention to the pixel format you decode to, 24bppRgb is a natural JPEG match so likely what you'll get out a codec but 32bppPArgb is by far the superior format (x10) if you display the images.

Comment: Which is basically what I said, I was just looking for something in GDI+ itself to avoid reinventing the wheel with another library to decode. The codecs themselves are interchangeable (hence the 10 lines of code to save a jpeg), you'd think I could tell it to just decode in a bitmap object I already created.

Comment: Hmm, no, you can't use words like "bitmap object" if you want to bring this to a good end.  That Bitmap constructor I linked to requires a *pointer*, not an object.  There is no magic incantation you can use to make the codecs wrapped by GDI+ do something else than what you already know.  Reusing a MemoryStream is of course trivial.

Comment: You're being pedantic, but ok, it allocates a bitmap-shaped chunk of memory (sized width * height * bpp + some stride + a header of sorts) for every stream I decode. Light or not, that is a useless step when I get 30 jpegs a second and they're all the same shape.

Comment: Asked and answered, the pointer you pass to the Bitmap constructor needs to point to that chunk of memory.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the only way I found too, it just felt weird I couldn't use the C# *decompressor* just because I didn't want it to allocate memory for me. So tldr is use libjpeg to draw to a bitmap :(

Comment: Had to leave for work but just to finish my thought: you'd think it would be trivial to add an overload to lock my bitmap's bits to write to instead of theirs. In fact looking at libjpeg, it decodes line by line, so the .NET one is probably similar. With a bit of math you could write a DrawImage overload that decodes a stream directly in a larger image without temporaries. Forget about net gains for a sec, isn't that an intriguing concept?

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you can try to **use WPF** and it's image component & rendering capability. AFAIK, there are several mentions that WPF Image classes have better performance than WinForm with it's GDI+ based classes.

**Second**, if you **still want to use WinForm** as UI, if you allowed to include reference to Systems.Windows.Media.Imaging (PresentationCore.dll), then you can try to use `JpegBitmapDecoder` class to decode the image, and then set the decoded pixels into your preallocated `Bitmap` instance.

There are several options on JpegBitmapDecoder constructor that you can tweak for (probably) better performance, i.e. create-options and cache-options --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602494.aspx

Then get the BitmapFrame instance as

```
BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = jpegBitmapDecoder.Frames[0];
```

BitmapFrame has several overloads for [CopyPixels method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CopyPixels.aspx). The method can copy to an Array or IntPtr. I believe another answer other than mine has already mentioned about IntPtr as raw pixel buffer in Bitmap, so you may copy the pixels from BitmapFrame directly into your preallocated Bitmap.

Comment: I can do that with GDI+ too. Basically `JpegBitmapDecoder` allocates an entire image *for each image stream*, same as the GDI+ `Bitmap` constructor. That's the step I want to avoid. Of course I know I can draw one bitmap over another.

Comment: Hmm, just clarify, you only need to create/allocate a `Bitmap` instance once, and then you can just "update" its content with latest picture, so that instance is reusable. But regardless of the selected API/classes, I think you should try to use profiler to get better illustration of what is the bottleneck (most resource intensive) part within your application.

Comment: Noted, but useless advice. It's covered by my original post!